# .text() is only working once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to get the `.text()` function to run properly in my function.

Every now and then, the page will display correctly but the majority of the time, the text does not change. The page starts with the `<p>` tag displaying 'Waiting', then the initial `.text()` in the `beforeSend:` works correctly and the text is changed to 'Processing request...', however from then on, the `.text()` function does not seem to work.

I have added in `console.log`s to see if the `msg` variable is being populated correctly and it is, but the `.text()` still isn't changing the `<p>` tag the second time around. It seems to be the same in all browsers.

This is my function:

```
function sendrequest(first, last, email) {
    var request = $.ajax({
        url:"/core/ajax/register.php",
        type:"POST",
        data: {uf:first,ul:last,ue:email},
        beforeSend: function(){
            forms.regFor.fadeOut(100, function(){
                $('p#msg').text('Processing request...');
            });
        }
    });

    request.done(function(data){
        var msg;

        if (data == 1){
            msg = "Thank you "+first+", your request has been sent.";
            console.log('Registered successfully');
        }else if (data == 2){
            msg = "It appears that you have already signed up.";
            console.log('Already signed up');
        }else{
            msg = "There has been an error.";
            console.log('Error on submission');
        }

        console.log(msg);

        $('p#msg').text(msg);
    });
}
```

I've probably missed something very simple, just can't seem to see it at all, hopefully someone can.

Comment: i've tired that, exactly the same outcome.

Comment: If it works sometimes and not other times, then I'd guess that you have a timing issue with your ajax call.  Perhaps you need to make sure the page is loaded before you try modify the page?  If the page is sometimes loaded from  the cache and thus loads quicker, it might work then making it available then, but other times it isn't ready yet when the ajax call completes.

Comment: What does the console show as being returned from the `register.php` script?

Comment: When in doubt create a JSFiddle to demonstrate the problem. Half the time you will spot the problem yourself while making a standalone  example.

Comment: BTW - you're sending `data` to the script and receiving `data` from it. Could you change the AJAX response to `response` for code clarity?

Comment: Ok so it seems it was timing after all. I added a 1 second delay on the php script and that has cleared up the problem. Working fine now, Thanks!

Comment: I hope that's only a temporary solution to verify the problem. It doesn't make sense to purposefully delay the server-side script just to fix a client-side problem (and it doesn't even work if there's a network error or something else that makes the request fail fast).

Comment: No I dont intend to leave the delay there. im going to look into removing the fadeOut as suggested below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the `fadeOut` in your `beforeSend` call.

In all likelyhood, the fadeOut isn't completing before the AJAX call does. So your AJAX `done` is triggered, then your fadeOut is completed and your fadeout callback takes place, destroying your AJAX `done` changes.

```
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('p#msg').text('Processing request...');
    }
```

If you feel you *must* have the fadeOut, then put your AJAX call in the fadeOut callback.

```
forms.regFor.fadeOut(100, function(){
    var request = $.ajax({
        url:"/core/ajax/register.php",
        type:"POST",
        data: {uf:first,ul:last,ue:email},
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('p#msg').text('Processing request...');
        }
    });
    request.done = // etc.
});
```